# How to solve different execution_date with start_date dag Airflow

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have an issue with some of my airflow dags, I have a target SLA of less than 6 hours execution_timedelta.
But what happens is some dags have big time difference between `execution_date` and `start_date`

What's wrong with this issue
Is it possible to limit the time between `execution_date` and `start_date`? eg time-out

Can someone help me to solve this problem in another way.

[image]

How to minimizing execution_timedelta less than 6 hours or same exact with start date

Note
This data get from airflow database
`dag_runs.start_date`
`dag_runs.execution_date`

Comment: I think you have got the wrong idea about the `start_date`. It is supposed to be a static date after which the scheduling of the DAG starts. This means the difference between `execution_date` and `start_date` will gradually increase with each run.
If you want to set SLA for your DAG run duration you could use `'sla':timedelta(hours=6)` in `default_args`.

Comment: @DarkMatter Thanks for your answer. but `start_date` what I used is to calculate `execution_date` so I get the exactly time delta execution (how late dag runs from the time it should be), the data i found on `dag_runs` table, not `start_date` in dag running for the first time.

Am I wrong in calculating my dag delay?

Comment: You have named your columns the same as airflow properties, which is confusing. I think I understand what you mean now. Can you share some parts of your DAG? Ideally, it should run according to your `schedule_interval`.

Comment: @DarkMatter oh ya Im sorry, I just follow the column names from the default table which are automatically created by airflow.
`duration` and `execution_timedelta` in minutes.
Dag Interval Schedule is `@daily` . 
I think, I make mistake for calculating `execution_timedelta`, because I assume `execution_date` is time it should be.
If I look in UI DAG Grid View, `start_date` equal Started and `execution_date` equal Data Interval Start.
I think the correct answer to calculate `execution_timedelta` = Started / `start_date` - (Data Interval start or `execution_date` + Interval Scheduler).